# GNU Assembler (Arm64). Parentheses in macro arguments references

Tags: arm64, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to find any information parentheses syntax for macro arguments in GNU Assembler. E.g. I have following code:

```
    .macro      do_block, enc, in, rounds, rk, rkp, i
    eor     \in\().16b, \in\().16b, v15.16b
    ...
```

(taken from [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm64/crypto/aes-neon.S))

What does paretheses in `\in\().16b` mean? Where to find documentaion for this syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found the answer. This is special syntax to escape macro-argument name.

From the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html#Macro):

> Note that since each of the macargs can be an identifier exactly as any other one permitted by the target architecture, there may be occasional problems if the target hand-crafts special meanings to certain characters when they occur in a special position. For example:
>
> ...
>
> problems might occur with the period character (‘.’) which is often allowed inside opcode names (and hence identifier names). So for example constructing a macro to build an opcode from a base name and a length specifier like this:
>
> ```
> .macro opcode base length
> \base.\length
> .endm
> ```
>
> and invoking it as ‘opcode store l’ will not create a ‘store.l’ instruction but instead > generate some kind of error as the assembler tries to interpret the text `\base.\length`.
>
> The string `\()` can be used to separate the end of a macro argument from the following text. eg:
>
> ```
>     .macro opcode base length
>     \base\().\length
>     .endm
> ```